# Can a class method singleton object respond to a delegate call?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, singleton, class-method

I have a `SettingsManager` singleton which handles user settings throughout my app (for example, whenever a sound is played in any view controller, the `SettingsManager` is checked to see if sound is turned on, and at what volume).

Can that class object (which I access with `[SettingsManager sharedManager]`) respond to a delegate message sent somewhere else? For example, if I toggle sound on in my `SettingsViewController`, can the class method object pick that up and go and save those changes to disk?

Comment: The easiest way to do what you want is to call your SettingsManager's save data method from the appropriate place, whether or not that's a delegate callback.

Comment: @AaronBrager It's a singleton, and sharedManager is a class method, not an instance method. I can't call other methods on it, can I?

Comment: sharedManager is a class method that returns one instance (the only instance) of your object.  Your singleton is still an instance that can have properties, methods, etc.

Comment: It would look something like `[[SettingsManager sharedManager] saveData];` and you'd have `- (void) saveData;` in your .h file

Comment: The `sharedManager` object has a `+` before its method declaration, meaning (as far as I know) that I can't call instance methods on it without creating an instance first. I don't want to do that.

Comment: You're not calling an instance method on a class method.  You're calling an instance method on an instantiated object returned by a class method.

Comment: I'm assuming sharedManager returns something, right?  The object that it returns is instantiated.

Comment: And if you look in your code for `sharedManager` I bet it has alloc/init in there.

Comment: Yes, it does, but I don't think Xcode knows what methods it has internally from an external view controller.

Comment: If it's returning a `SettingsManager` object then Xcode will let you call any instance method declared in your SettingsManager.h file.  Try it out.

Comment: So you just declare method with `+` thing that you are talking about, and save necessary data if you don't want create an object of your "singleton" class, like `[MySoCalledSingleton saveData]`.

Comment: (Which is why I wanted a delegate in the first place)

Comment: I've just saved things in the viewcontroller. But thanks for the attempt. Apple sure do like to make things as convoluted as possible, don't they?

Comment: (And if you wanna post an answer I'll gladly accept it!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your singleton, once instantiated, can of course act as a delegate. In the end it is an object like any other object too. Its only difference is that it is instantiated only once.

However, if you only access it through class methods and do not store any data in properties, ivars, etc, then it may not be instantiated at all. I am not sure whether it is a true singleton in that case but I have seen people calling it a singleton although it never gets actually instantiated. In that case, within class methods, `self` always refers to the class rather than an instance. And a class cannot act as delegate.

So, depending on what your singleton looks like, the answer is yes or no.